# Erlang implementing an amb operator.

Tags: erlang, continuations, continuation-passing

On wikipedia it says that using call/cc you can implement the amb operator for nondeterministic choice, and my question is how would you implement the amb operator in a language in which the only support for continuations is to write in continuation passing style, like in erlang?

Answer (score 3):

If you can encode the constraints for what constitutes a successful solution or choice as guards, list comprehensions can be used to generate solutions. For example, the [list comprehension documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html) shows an example of solving [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), which is a problem frequently solved using `amb` (see for example [exercise 4.35 of SICP, 2nd edition](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-28.html)). Here's the more efficient solution, `pyth1/1`, shown on the list comprehensions page:

```
pyth1(N) ->
    [ {A,B,C} ||
        A <- lists:seq(1,N-2),
        B <- lists:seq(A+1,N-1),
        C <- lists:seq(B+1,N),
        A+B+C =< N,
        A*A+B*B == C*C 
    ].
```

One important aspect of `amb` is efficiently searching the solution space, which is done here by generating possible values for `A`, `B`, and `C` with `lists:seq/2` and then constraining and testing those values with guards. Note that the page also shows a less efficient solution named `pyth/1` where `A`, `B`, and `C` are all generated identically using `lists:seq(1,N)`; that approach generates all permutations but is slower than `pyth1/1` (for example, on my machine, `pyth(50)` is 5-6x slower than `pyth1(50)`).

If your constraints can't be expressed as guards, you can use pattern matching and try/catch to deal with failing solutions. For example, here's the same algorithm in `pyth/1` rewritten as regular functions `triples/1` and the recursive `triples/5`:

```
-module(pyth).
-export([triples/1]).

triples(N) ->
    triples(1,1,1,N,[]).
triples(N,N,N,N,Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
triples(N,N,C,N,Acc) ->
    triples(1,1,C+1,N,Acc);
triples(N,B,C,N,Acc) ->
    triples(1,B+1,C,N,Acc);
triples(A,B,C,N,Acc) ->
    NewAcc = try
                 true = A+B+C =< N,
                 true = A*A+B*B == C*C,
                 [{A,B,C}|Acc]
             catch
                 error:{badmatch,false} ->
                     Acc
             end,
    triples(A+1,B,C,N,NewAcc).
```

We're using pattern matching for two purposes:

- In the function heads, to control values of `A`, `B` and `C` with respect to `N` and to know when we're finished
- In the body of the final clause of `triples/5`, to assert that conditions `A+B+C =< N` and `A*A+B*B == C*C` match `true`

If both conditions match `true` in the final clause of `triples/5`, we insert the solution into our accumulator list, but if either fails to match, we catch the `badmatch` error and keep the original accumulator value.

Calling `triples/1` yields the same result as the list comprehension approaches used in `pyth/1` and `pyth1/1`, but it's also half the speed of `pyth/1`. Even so, with this approach any constraint could be encoded as a normal function and tested for success within the try/catch expression.